# Pass request information to Spring AuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

How can I pass request specific information to an `AuthenticationProvider` from a `Filter` without creating a custom `Authentication` ?

The `AuthenticationProvider` signature is as below:

```
interface AuthenticationProvider {
    Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication);
}
```

I'm thinking something similar to the static `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` but with request specific information.

---

### Background

The reason I want it is because I want to implement a switching authentication provider that delegates in runtime to another `AuthenticationProvider`

```
public class SwitchingAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private AuthenticationProvider[] authProviders = // ...

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        return authProvider[GetCurrentContext.getIndex()].authenticate(authentication);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Authentication` has a `details` property.  Can you use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide your own implementation of `AuthenticationEntryPoint` which have access to `HttpServletRequest`. In `AuthenticationEntryPoint` implementation put all attribute that you need in your switching `AuthenticationProvider`, in `RequestContextHolder` as given below

```
RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().setAttribute(attributeName, attibuteValue, scope);
```

At the end you can retrieve these attribute in your authentication provider as given below

```
RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getAttribute(attributeName,scope);
```